# Why does WebAssembly.Memory take `initial` and `maximum` in units of number of pages, rather than number of bytes

Tags: javascript, webassembly

I will almost always be computing my memory needs in the unit of bytes. I wouldn't know how large a "page" is, I had to look it up ([MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/JavaScript_interface/Memory) it's 64KB). It's not obvious that the size of a page even *should* be a fixed (documentable) platform-independent constant. I'm unable to source a reason or even an attestation for the page size being that in MDN's spec link.

I can only think of really bad reasons for it to be this way and I want to figure out whether it really is that bad.

Comment: I think it's more readable (I for one don't want to write 640000 just so I can get 1 page)? What other answer can we give other than "the people at ECMA said so"? And it would help if you shared your reasoning.

Answer (score 2):

The page size for wasm is documented in the spec: https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/exec/runtime.html#memory-instances

The value is 64k rather than 640k.

WebAssembly itself is designed to be a compiler target rather than hand written, so normally the toolchain will set this value rather than a human.  As it happens, if you use clang, or emscripten then the memory size, as specified on the command line, is actually in bytes rather than pages: https://lld.llvm.org/WebAssembly.html#cmdoption-initial-memory

Comment: Ah, right, the MDN page implies it's 64K, I misread it.

Answer (score 1):

Wasm memory size can only be chosen in steps of pages (64 KiB), because that generally makes memory bounds checks using hardware virtual memory techniques more feasible.

Comment: This worried me slightly to hear, as it sounded as if it would place a pretty large lower bound on how compact a wasm runtime instance could be, but I suppose if I don't mind the memory access overhead, a compliant runtime could just not actually allocate memory at the top of the page until the wasm writes something to it?

Comment: Suggest completing this answer with: - So, the reason it doesn't allow odd memory sizes is that doing so would require the runtime to be ready to bounds-check every access to memory in a slower way (to potentially panic if out of bounds). A sufficiently smart runtime could be made to switch between a fast or slow bounds check depending on exact amount of memory allocated, but that would be a very laborious requirement to impose on implementors for a memory error behavior that no wasm program we can think of would need.